# How to isolate a WAP (WiFi router) from the internet, but not the LAN?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, lan

// This is my first foray into actually asking a question on stack-exchange, if I have erred in location or protocol please let me know!

Basic Problem:

I am trying to set up a Wifi router in an specific area, so that when connected I can access some utilities/services that are available on our LAN, but at the same time not access the internet. These utilities/services are hosted by a server on the LAN, and I want them to also be available to the rest of the (internet-connected) LAN. As a final note, I would like to preserve whatever form of name resolution (DNS) I end up adopting within the LAN.

Context/Details:

An example of one of the services is Kiwix, which currently hosts Wikipedia some other machining references. Another is WikiJS.

I currently plan on using an old Linksys WRT54GL with stock firmware as the WAP, however if DD-WRT or different hardware would be a better choice that is not an obstacle (read: VLAN?).

Research/Current Work:

I tried hunting around the web, and here, but was unsuccessful in either finding anything terribly similar or describing my problem.

That said, I gather there may be many ways to get the job done. The simplest, which I have not yet tried, would seem to be connection an existing (internet connected) router/switch into one of the LAN ports of the router, leaving the WAN/Internet port empty. This will be my first attempt, but I figured I would seek confirmation as well.

Alternatively, I know there are potential router firmware options that would facilitate behavior like this, perhaps involving a local DNS server?

And "lastly", we have a pfSense firewall at the edge of the LAN, and my understanding is that this could easily be utilized to restrict access to the internet for a particular WAP.

If anyone could offer confirmation as to whether one of these, or another approach would solve my problem, thank you.

Comment: Run NAT on the AP so that all the traffic from its wireless clients comes from the same IP address. Then configure your Internet router (or your pfSense box or whatever) to forbid that IP address from getting to your Internet connection.

Comment: Ddwrt & iptables would also work